# How to save a timestamp in firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I save the Map showen below to a firestore, but I want to save also a timestamp which should have the time and date a user picked with a date and time picker. The date is already in 'dd.MM.yyyy' formatted and the time is something like '6:58 PM'. The date is the variable `date` and the time is the variable `time`. How can I save a timestamp with the value `time` and `date`?

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'name': userName,
      'userUID': userUIDglobal,
      'time: '//here I want to safe the timestamp
    };
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('seller')
        .document(documentID)
        .collection('test')
        .add(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use server generated value which would be better so you don't depend on device time, use this:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'name': userName,
      'userUID': userUIDglobal,
      'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    };
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('seller')
        .document(documentID)
        .collection('test')
        .add(data);
```

But pay attention that if you have an active collection snapshot subscription when you're writing this document to the collection you'll get one snapshot with `null` value for `time` (because of optimistic commit) and then when you get the data from the server you'll get the actual millisecond value.

EDIT: You can prevent the optimistic commit emitting `null` value for the timestamp by doing this write as part of a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting it to epoch time as int store it in your cloud and re-convert to DateTime after fetching it.

Example:

```
// Convert DateTime to int
int time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  'name': userName,
  'userUID': userUIDglobal,
  'time': time
};

// To safely convert it back to DateTime

DateTime fetchedTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data['time']);
```

Comment: but how can I use then the date and the time the user picked?

Comment: You can use the DateTime constructor. Constructs a DateTime instance specified in the local time zone.

For example, to create a new DateTime object representing the 7th of September 2017, 5:30pm

var dentistAppointment = new DateTime(2017, 9, 7, 17, 30);